# How to get the read only status of a field on a page layout from the API?

Tags: api, page-layout, read-only, react-native

I'm using net.describeLayout from react-native-force to get the fields on the page layouts. However the problem is that it doesn't seem that the 'read-only' property from the page layout gets returned on the field nor on the layoutItems properties: editableForNew and editableForCreate.

Is there any way to get this information returned via the api?

Comment: What's your intent? To edit the page layout, or to render a user interface?

Comment: I'm doing a UI for the mobile app, I would like fields that are marked as read-only to not appear in the edit record form I've got